# Flatten the mesh

Tags: mesh

I was trying to combine a drawing I found on the Internet, a face and a body.
Once joined however I encountered problems, vertices are not the same number so I tried to connect them but the result is as follows

How can I resolve this?

I add the file (the original and my version), Maybe it is better to do a new join. Let me what do you think.

[image: result]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bad shading comes from bad split normals (which are the normals that determine the shading), go into the *Object Data panel > Geometry Data > click on Clear Custom Split Normals Data*:

[image]

Then activate the *Auto Merge* and the *Snap to Vertex* options and simplify the topology:

[image]

If you want to remove the *Sharp Edges* (the blue edges), select all and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Clear Sharp*.